# Is there a sequence of $v_{n}$ such that $G=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2\tan^{-1}(v_{n})}{\pi}> 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, infinite-product

Let $G=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2\tan^{-1}(v_{n})}{\pi}$, where $v_{n}$ is an increasing, monotonic sequence of natural numbers: is it true that there is no sequence of $v_{n}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $G>1$ for sequences $v_{n}$ such that $G$ is nonzero? 
I know that $v_{n}$ has to be spread more thinly than just $v_{n}=n$ -- in that case $G=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at |G| it is product of factors of the form $|\frac{\arctan{x}}{\pi/2}|<1$, since arctan has its image the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, and therefore $|G|<1$ for any sequence $(v_n)$.

Answer (score 3):

To ensure that $G\ne0$ is more interesting: this holds if and only if the series $\displaystyle\sum\frac1{v_n}$ converges.

Comment: Perhaps needs some explanation.  asymptotics of $\tan^{-1}(v)$ as $v \to \infty$.